# Bind JSON Array to select

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to bind a JSON array, which is the result of an Ajax call, to a `<select/>` element.

A sample of the JSON structure is seen below:

```
[{"JD_No":1,"JD_Name":"Network Administrator"}, {"JD_No":2,"JD_Name":"System Administrator"}]
```

What I need to achieve is to extract the `JD_No` value and `JD_Name` value of each element and bind them to a html `<select/>`

I must also state that the JSON Key is dynamic, so referencing a specific Key Name will not be possible.

Any help please?

Comment: Place it in the `data-*` property, then recall it. You can use jQuery's `.data()` for this.

Comment: are you saying JD_No will not always be the key?

Comment: That is correct Alex. But the structure will always be 2 KeyValue pairs within a single object

Comment: when you say bind, you mean add options with those values to the select?

Comment: Indeed Koala, each object will be bound as an option in a select element.

Comment: take a look at my answer, it should handle different JSON keys as long as there are only 2 keys. One key is the ID number and the other is the name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to bind dynamic properties to the select? If you can assume that the list of objects will always be returned with a specific amount of properties in a specific order, you can access the properties based on their INDEX.

The following example gets a key and value from an object:

```
for (var i in myArray) {
    var obj = myArray[i];
    var index = 0;
    var key, val;
    for (var prop in obj) {
        switch (index++) {
            case 0:
                key = obj[prop];
                break;
            case 1:
                val = obj[prop];
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    $("select").append("<option value=\"" + key + "\">" + val + "</option>");
}
```

Comment: each array item is an object, you cant access it like an array.

Comment: you're right - you have to access the associative "property array" by the key. I amended my answer.

Answer (score 3):

in jQuery you can do this:

you can check if the value is a type number, if not then it is a name.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Lf2t/) here

```
var jsonString = '[{"JD_No":1,"JD_Name":"Network Administrator"}, {"JD_No":2,"JD_Name":"System Administrator"}]';

var json_data = JSON.parse(jsonString);

for(var i = 0; i < json_data.length; i++){

    var option = $("<option>");

    for( var key in json_data[i] ){
        // There should only be two keys, if its a number its ID, else option name
        if( typeof json_data[i][key] === "number" ){
            option.attr("value", json_data[i][key]);
        }else{
            option.html(json_data[i][key]);
        }
    }

    $("select").append(option);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/SPMJz/

HTML

```
<select id="select"></select>
```

Javascript

```
window.onload = function(){
    var data = [
        {"JD_No":1,"JD_Name":"Network Administrator"},
        {"JD_No":2,"JD_Name":"System Administrator"}
    ];

    populateSelect(data, 'number', 'string');
}

function populateSelect(data, idType, nameType){
    if(!data || !data[0]){
        return;
    }

    var select  = document.getElementById('select');
    var keys    = Object.keys(data[0]);
    var idKey   = typeof(parseInt(keys[0])) == idType   ? keys[0] : keys[1];
    var nameKey = typeof(parseInt(keys[0])) == nameType ? keys[0] : keys[1];

    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.value = data[i][idKey];
        option.label = data[i][nameKey];
        select.appendChild(option);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the assumption that your option's value attribute will always be a number.

```
var json = [{"JD_No":1,"JD_Name":"Network Administrator"}, {"JD_No":2,"JD_Name":"System Administrator"}];

var options = [], key, value;

json.forEach(function(obj) {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(k) {
        if(typeof obj[k] === "number") {
            key = obj[k];
        }
        else {
            value = obj[k];
        }
    });
    options.push({'key': key, 'value': value}); //or append it directly to select
});

options.forEach(function(option) {
    var option = $('<option>').attr('value', this.key).html(this.value);
    $('#slt').append(option);
});
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Cn7eu/2/)

A jQuery solution:

```
$.each(json, function() {
    $.each(this, function(k, v) {
        if(typeof v === 'number') {
            key = v;
        }
        else {
            value = v;
        }
    });
    options.push({'key': key, 'value': value}); ////or append it directly to select
});


$.each(options, function() {
    var option = $('<option>').attr('value', this.key).html(this.value);
    $('#slt').append(option);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider that `json` is the object that array of objects you have in question. Iterate the array, collect each `obj`, access the `keys` as you require. Generate an element and store `data-` attributes equal to the `keys in the array.`

```
$.each(json, function(i, obj){
    $('body').append('<select data-no="'+obj.JD_No+'" data-name="'+obj.JD_Name+'"></select>');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but as stated in my original post, the Key names will be dynamic and not known at the time.

Answer (score 0):

let `jsonArray` be your json data, then you can bind the data to a `select` element using the following code

```
$.each(jsonArray, function (index, item) {
                 $('#ddl').append($('<option></option>').val(item.JD_No).html(item.JD_Name));
             });
```